# generating .ui file from source files (.cpp and .h)

Tags: qt4

wanted to know is there way to get .ui file from .cpp & .h file. i have written simple gui application (with out using qtdesigner). how do i get .ui file from source file.

Answer (score 0):

No way.

If the application is simple, rewrite it. If it is complicated, you could use QMetaObject facilities for reverse-engineering QObjects at run-time. It is possible to get the childtree, query values of properties and get signatures of signals/slots.

I've implemented such a GUI-debugger but never tried to save data in ui-files. Could be an interesting idea for a holiday project :-)

However, I would suggest reimplementing GUIs in QtCreator - it is easy and fun!